# HttpClient / HttpRequestMessage accept header parameters cannot have spaces

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm dealing with an API that requires me to set the header `application/json;masked=false` in order to unmask some information. When setting the header using

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;masked=false");
```

it appears as though a space is being added between the `;` and `masked` making the output header `application/json; masked=false`. Unfortunately this API I'm working with appears to be checking only against the literal `application/json;masked=false` without the space. I know the header works, because if I use it without the space in postman it works fine. If I use the one C# is generating in postman, it does not.

Is there any way to override this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the source for WebRequest at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebHeaderCollection.cs,462.  As for a fix, it doesn't look good, as all headers go through some 'tidy up', probably due to it being in some RFC somewhere.  If you can work out where the API you are using is wrong in the RFC, it might be easier to tell them they have a non-conforming implementation and they should fix it.

Comment: FYI just tried it and this is the same in Framework 4.5. Not sure it can be easily fixed at your end (you know things are bad when you're reading pages on w3c.org).

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the source link! I honestly forgot about that. At this point I'm thinking you're probably right, and we need to contact them and tell them their API is non-conforming.

Comment: @DaveBecker Yeah pretty much lol. Thanks for testing it in Framework though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, so through some digging, we ended up finding this github issue for the problem: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/18449 where they have a workaround which uses reflection.

I adopted their workaround to what I'm doing like so:

```
        request.Headers.Add("Accept", contentType);
        foreach (var v in request.Headers.Accept)
        {
            if (v.MediaType.Contains("application/json"))
            {
                var field = v.GetType().GetTypeInfo().BaseType.GetField("_mediaType", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                field.SetValue(v, "application/json;masked=false");
                v.Parameters.Clear();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for posting all of this.  I have a ticket open with, what I assume is, the same company you're having this space issue with with unmask sensitive data.  Hopefully they conform to the standard soon.  Thank you very much for posting your workaround.  Glad I'm not the only one facing the same issues.

Comment: @MattH No problem, and if it's a company that deals with pay, we probably are :) We had actually e-mailed them and they notified us of that open issue, then said they can't support it :/ But, the issue is in .netcore "Future" milestone, so hopefully they either conform or MS lets us force using exactly what we put in.

Answer (score 4):

This problem still exists in .NET 5, but I solved it by using:

`request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json;masked=false");`

No reflection needed when using this method.