# HttpClient / HttpRequestMessage adding white spaces to headers

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

I just got into .net core due to the features it has to offer for HttpClient (example is setting the keep-alive header capped down). 
**I'm using 2.1 net core and C# 7.3**

**My issue**

My issue is specifically about setting the "Accept" and "Accept-Language" headers. The site I'm trying to reach parses these two headers as is, meaning it must have the same exact format (including spaces).

Using fiddler (and some other tools) to grab my request.

1. I'm capturing the "Accept" header as the following: (incorrect format)

```
text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml; q=0.9, image/webp, image/apng, */*; q=0.8, application/signed-exchange; v=b3
```

instead of: (correct format)

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
```

2. "Accept-Language" header as the following: (incorrect format)

```
en-US, en; q=0.9, ar; q=0.8, und; q=0.7
```

Instead of: (correct format)

```
en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8,und;q=0.7
```

I'm simulating a GET request using HttpClient with the help of HttpRequestMessage.

**What I have tried**

1. Tried both settings my headers in the HttpClient instance and firing off a HttpRequestMessage with it's own headers, none are working.
2. Tried lots of solutions online which didn't work, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194549/httpclient-httprequestmessage-accept-header-parameters-cannot-have-spaces)
3. Splitting the header through multiple `.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation`
4. Tried HttpWebRequests as well. No luck.
   One thing to note, due to my project I also like to stick with the HttpClient.

You'll find below my current code

```
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseCookies = false,
            AllowAutoRedirect = false,
            Proxy = new WebProxy("localhost:8888") });

var httpReq = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"myurl");


            httpReq.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Host", "myurl");
            httpReq.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Connection", "keep-alive");
            httpReq.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Cookie", $"cookie");
            httpReq.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
            httpReq.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", Data.user_agent);
            httpReq.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            httpReq.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3");
            httpReq.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Referer", Data.homeUrl);
            httpReq.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8,und;q=0.7");

            req = await client.SendAsync(httpReq);
```

As noted before, all the other headers are working fine. Just these two Accept and Accept-Language are being inputted differently.

Comment: Have you tried adding the headers individually, using `httpReq.Headers.AcceptLanguage.Add("en-US");` etc.?

Comment: @spodger ,yep. I have tried that as well. It shouldn't affect my input as it only has to do with header name and not value?

Comment: Please don't "bump" questions

Comment: Try to generate the request in Postman, generate the C# code and compare it to yours.

Comment: @mr5 when using postman's C# generated code (using restclient) outputs the same result, adding white spaces to the headers.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like it's hardcoded in corefx, look here:

```
destination.Append(' ');
```

Full method:

```
internal static void ToString(ObjectCollection<NameValueHeaderValue> values, char separator, bool leadingSeparator,
            StringBuilder destination)
        {
            Debug.Assert(destination != null);

            if ((values == null) || (values.Count == 0))
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                if (leadingSeparator || (destination.Length > 0))
                {
                    destination.Append(separator);
                    destination.Append(' ');
                }
                value.AddToStringBuilder(destination);
            }
        }
```

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a10890f4ffe0fadf090c922578ba0e606ebdd16c/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Headers/NameValueHeaderValue.cs#L183

I don't know how to override this but maybe you could create a new issue on GitHub?

EDIT: Found an issue regarding this and bumped it: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/18449

Comment: It appears as if whoever added the separator may have extracted it from the examples provided in RFC7231#section-5.3 . There is no mention of whitespace treatment in 5.3 although there is treatment of whitespace explicitly given in other sections and when it is mentioned it provides guidance when provided whitespace will be invalid or ignored by the recipient. The separator should probably be changed to match basic convention: unnecessary whitespace should be avoided when the primary recipient is not a human.

Comment: @K.AlanBates I found this issue on GitHub where they are discussing this: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/18449

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that an issue report was actually made (good thing I'm not the only person?). I'll see if I can report it directly to Microsoft                                           @JOSEFtw